# Disable diagonal following of player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a script for my player where I have disabled diagonal move. I then created a script for his dog companion that follows him in the world and it's almost perfected except when I do a direction change from left/right to up/down or vice versa the dog will follow at a diagonal and looks really weird since there is no animations and he basically slides there. I tried to disable diagonal like how I did for the player but it doesn't work. Is there a way to go about this or would it be better to just add in a diagonal animation for just the dog?

```
public class Bowser : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Transform target;
    private Vector2 move;
    private Animator anim;

    private void Awake()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        move.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        move.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.position) > 1.5)
        {
            // Code attempt to get rid of diagonal movement
            if (move.x != 0) move.y = 0;

            if (move != Vector2.zero)
            {
                anim.SetFloat("moveX", move.x);
                anim.SetFloat("moveY", move.y);
                anim.SetBool("moving", true);
            }
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
            anim.SetBool("moving", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I tried to disable diagonal like how I did for the player but it doesn't work` you show your player code but could you share the one that is not working as expected and describe a bit further what exactly `it doesn't work` means?

Comment: It slides diagonal which is awkward since there is no animation. Is like it to either follow the same path as the player is using or just not move until it's inline with the player character. The above code had the non-working line commented which was `if (move.x != 0) move.y = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just checking for `0` you could just use the bigger value

```
if (Mathf.Abs(move.x) > (Mathf.Abs(move.y)) move.y = 0;
else move.x = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks this put me in the right direction to solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

it would be better if you just provided diagonal animations for the dog

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice in the end I found that it became a smoother transition to just add this

```
        if (Mathf.Abs(move.x) > .01f)
            targetPosition.y = transform.position.y;
        if (Mathf.Abs(move.y) > .01f)
            targetPosition.x = transform.position.x;
```

and then change all my target.Position to the targetPosition